# Can I create custom Annotation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, customization, wrapper

I know there are limited ways to create own custom Annotations in Java. One article describes [here](https://dzone.com/articles/how-annotations-work-java) a way. I wonder, is it possible to create custom `Annotation` in `Swift` as well? For example, I have a `BaseViewController` and I want to test if any of its subclass created added annotation to log function names or not.

```
class BaseViewController: ViewController {

    func viewWillAppear() {
        // want to get if annotation added from caller and use
        super.viewWillAppear()
    } 
}

class SubViewController: BaseViewController {

    @LogEntrance    // custom annotation
    func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
    } 
}
```

If there is no way to use like it, How can I controller it otherwise? any workaround?

---

<sup>**Context** - I would be needing this for my large scale `Swift` app. I am using logger but I want to give developers flexibility to log classes, functions entrance and exits. Currently developers are putting logs at the entrance and exits of their functions and I want to give them annotation if possible.</sup>

Comment: Can you please clarify the context where you would need that.

Comment: @PGDev I updated the post. Please see the context.

Comment: You can do that only for properties. https://nshipster.com/propertywrapper/